# Could not find MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v8.0.1) on Cocoapods

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We use Cocoapods as dependency for our app.
Couldn´t find the new version for IOS v. 8.0.1 in there.
https://cocoapods.org/pods/MarketingCloudSDK

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

New versions of the SDK >=v8.0.0 are not available in Cocoapods. You have to use Swift Package Manager: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html

Comment: Whats the rationale for this?

Swift Package Manager poses challenges for teams behind corporate proxies.

Also many of hybrid apps still rely on Cocoapods.